# cdrom line in "Other Software" in "Software & Updates"

Tags: software-center, repository, software-sources

On 16.04 I have this:

**cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS_Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719)]/ xenial** main restricted

...and it's disabled by default. What is it and why is it labeled "cdrom"? *(It's some repository, right?)* What will I get if I enable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it IS the CD-ROM or DVD player in your system. If you put one in that has debian install files the system will happily add them to. Ubuntu software centre.

In general keep it disabled. It is unlikely you have a CD or DVD that has debian files.